# Spring Configuration with Template Dependencies

Tags: java, spring, configuration, dependency-injection

I have a class `TemplateObject` that has a well defined dependency structure. The class has some unique attribute, `KindOfObject`, and there is a singleton instance for each unique value. In this case there are 3 `KindOfObject` values, so there should be 3 singleton instances of `TemplateObject`. The same holds true for `Dependency1` and `Dependency2`.

```
enum KindOfObject {

    KIND_A,
    KIND_B,
    KIND_C;

}

class TemplateObject {

    private KindOfObject kindOfObject;

    private Dependency1 dependency1;

    private Dependency2 dependency2;

    ...

}

class Dependency1 {

   private KindOfObject kindOfObject;

   ...
}

class Dependency2 {

   private KindOfObject kindOfObject;

   ...

}
```

The values to inject in the dependencies of `TemplateObject` are driven by the value of`KindOfObject`. A `TemplateObject` whose `KindOfObject` is `KIND_A` would have a `KIND_A` `Dependency1`, and `KIND_A` `Dependency2`, etc. This makes the corresponding Spring Configuration verbose, especially when the number of unique values and dependencies is large.

```
@Configuration
class ProjectConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Dependency1 dependency1A() {
        return new Dependency1(KIND_A, ...);
    }

    @Bean
    public Dependency1 dependency1B() {
        return new Dependency1(KIND_B, ...);
    }

    ...

    @Bean
    public Dependency2 dependency2A() {
        return new Dependency2(KIND_A, ...);
    }

    @Bean
    public Dependency2 dependency2B() {
        return new Dependency1(KIND_B, ...);
    }

    ...

    @Bean
    public TemplateObject templateObjectA() {
        return new TemplateObject(KIND_A, dependency1A(), dependency2A(), ...);
    }

    @Bean
    public TemplateObject templateObjectB() {
        return new TemplateObject(KIND_B, dependency1B(), dependency2B(), ...);
    }

    ...
}
```

There are certainly ways to reorganize these classes to avoid this problem, but for now, let's assume that is out of the question. We should also assume that `Dependency1` and `Dependency2` may also have dependencies. Is there any way of simplifying this kind of Spring Configuration?

Comment: Think of a Bean Factory method.